# for loop to check if a box is selected

Tags: actionscript

i have the following:

```
for(var i:Number = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
if ( eval("chk"+i).selected == false ) {
    btnSubmit.enabled = false;
    } else {
    btnSubmit.enabled = true;
   }
}
```

i have 10 boxes. If anyone of them is checked, then i enable the form submit button. for some reason, the above code works for only the 10th item. any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through each checkbox in turn, and setting the submit button to be enabled if that checkbox is ticked, **and disabled if it is not**.

This means that the last checkbox is the only one that counts, since every checkbox undoes whatever the previous one did.

Try this instead:

```
btnSubmit.enabled = false;
for(var i:Number = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   if ( eval("chk"+i).selected == true ) {
      btnSubmit.enabled = true;
   }
}
```

Now you set the button to be disabled, and then only set it to be enabled if any checkbox is ticked.

Comment: I would add that you should change the `eval` statement.  `this['chk'+i].selected` should be used in its place.

Answer (score 0):

add a break statement after the btnSubmit.enabled = true to stop looping immediately.  small thing in this case.... but...